Влияние раскладки клавиатуры на pyautogui.hotkey
Для копирования выделенного текста в буфер обмена использую:
import pyautogui
#копируем выделенный текст в буфер обмена с помощью Ctrl C
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')

Это работает только если раскладка клавиатуры английская. Если переключить раскладку на русский, то копирование в буфер обмена не происходит. Как это исправить?

Для копирования в буфер (и других операций с ним) никаких модулей вообще не нужно, по крайней мере в Windows и в tkinter. Текстовые виджеты tkinter сами по себе поддерживают работу с буфером если раскладка английская. Если же нужна возня с буфером в других раскладках, будет столько избыточного кода, привязанного к каждому виджету, что неизвестно что хуже. Я потратил много времени на эту проблему, она не стоит усилий. Хотите привязывать к каждому виджету с помощью bind эмуляцию нажатия ctrl+c, ctrl+v, ctrl+a, ctrl+x? Это возможно. Но зачем?

Ну как зачем?  Если на компьютере в этот момент клавиатура в русской раскладке, то программа не будет работать. Или для вас это не важно?

Что значит "не будет работать"? Если в интерфейсе tkinter ПО ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЮ прописано, что взять в буфер - это нажать ctrl+c (англ.), это означает, что надо нажать на ctrl и АНГЛИЙСКУЮ букву C. Если Вы можете нажать на английскую букву C в русской раскладке, сделайте это. Да, пользователи Windows  привыкли к тому, что буфер работает в любой раскладке, но в Питоне это не так. Всё, что Вам остаётся, это вручную эмулировать ситуацию: нажимаю ctrl+с (рус), а нечто при этом в фоне нажимает ctrl+c (англ.). Хочется долбиться с этим на каждом шагу? Кто ж запретит?

@winkot Как вариант: можно сперва проверять раскладку, если она ру - просто переключить её.

Да, только как это сделать?
