Не корректно работает pyautogui.hotkey
Вставляю в буфер обмена выделенную строку с помощью
import pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')

Когда есть выделенная строка то все работает. Но если выделенной строки нет и запустить скрипт, то получаю сообщение:
KeyboardInterrupt: Execution interrupted. Как это исправить?

Скорее всего проблема в том, что Питон связан прочно с консолью. Увы, Ctrl+C в консоли при отсутствии выделенного текста интерпретируется как прерывание работы скрипта. Попробуйте другой вариант, например:
import keyboard
keyboard.send('ctrl+c')

Оно не выведет на экран ошибку вроде бы, но всё равно как-то не хочет работать с пустым наполнением идеально.
Я не понимаю, зачем вообще использовать эти руки-крюки-глюки? Работа с буфером, как минимум, встроена в виджетах tkinter. Я догадываюсь, что и другие писатели gui догадываются о существовании работы с буфером и встроили её в свои виджеты.

Каким образом с помощью tkinter можно скопировать выделенный текст? Т.е. сделать аналог Ctrl+C?

Я ж написал - ВСТРОЕНО. Это значит, что в любом текстовом поле работают CTRL+C, CTRL+A, CTRL+V, CTRL+X. Но! Как видите, вводить надо именно английские буквы, то есть текущей должна быть английская клавиатура.

Не вводить английские буквы, а нажимать на клавиши - оговорился я.

Вам не надоело ещё эти темы с раскладками мусолить? Уже ж сто раз в других Ваших темах всё расписали. Работает буфер! Безо всяких писанин. В английской раскладке. Вот Ваши темы с ответами:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1596878/%d0%92%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-pyautogui-hotkey

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1596920/%d0%a1%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b8
